# how to get a the value of an http post as a whole? parsing restful post

Tags: java, http, rest, post

Is it my ideea or in rest-web services a post comes "with no name", so say something...

I mean, is the post the whole body, minus headers???

so, how can I parse such a post message with java?

do I have to use

HttpServletRequest.getInputStream?

http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/java/servlet2.2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

any useful example?

and how do I make such a call? I mean, posting value in the body and not in a specific parameter...

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side code would look like the following:

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    input.append(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Where request is the HttpServletRequest. For testing this from the client side, you can use [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691) with Firefox.

Comment: thanks a lot...

one more question, would it be more perfomant to preallocate space for the line variable? and is there any limitation to the size of a String variable in java???

Comment: If you have an idea of the average size of the POST contents then initializing the StringBuilder with that capacity would be beneficial. Depending on what you want to do with the data you might be better of working with the stream directly instead of buffering it into a String. See http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=658589&start=0 for a discussion about maximum String size.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) is really useful for this sort of thing. It is acts as a standard http proxy on your local machine. You can view the post body and headers etc in it's interface. You just have to tell your code to use an HTTP proxy (usually just 1 or 2 lines of )